# Selecting Parent database entry based on child column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

I'm attempting to select a database entry, based on the value of a column in a child table.

Specifically, I have a table containing the names and contact info of company officers, model: `Officer`.  An officer `has_many :roles` (CEO, CFO, President etc); this allows an officer to be both President and CEO, COO and CTO and other such common combinations.

**The problem:** I'm struggling to select the officer, based on a particular role for the company.  (Say I want to get the name of the CEO of the company.)

So I've set up the following:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :officers
  has_many :roles, through: :officers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :officers
end
```

and

```
class Officer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles

  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
end
```

and

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :officer
end
```

So I've tried `company.officer.where(roles.role_string: "Chairman of the Board")` ...nope

and I've tried `company.roles.where(role_string: "Chairman of the Board").officer`  ...also nope

Any guidance would be appreciated!  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nithin many thanks for the reply.  That seems to have gotten me farther.  How might I ask for a value in a column with that?  I tried `Role.includes(:officers).where(role_string: "Chairman of the Board").fname` (trying to get the officer's first name) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I solved it with the following: (seemed most efficient)

```
@officer_id=company.roles.where(role_string: "President").first.officer_id
@officer=company.officers.find(@officer_id)
```

The reason for the `first.officer_id` was that only one officer/company is allowed to have a given role, even though an officer has many roles.  There's probably a more elegant way to do this but the above works for now.

Answer (score 1):

try this

1.

```
@roles = Role.includes(:officers).where(role_string: "Chairman of the Board")
```

loop and find the officer.

```
@roles.each do |role|
 puts role.officer
end
```

2.

```
Company.includes(:roles).where('roles.role_string =?', "Chairman of the Board")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I gave the first one a shot but couldn't figure out how to ultimately reference a column in the :officers table.  say I wanted to reference the officer column `fname`, I tried `Role.includes(:officers).where(role_string: "Chairman of the Board").fname` but it didn't work.  How might I get the column value with this?

Answer (score 0):

This will lead to a n:m relation:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :officers
  has_many :roles, through: :officers
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :officers
  has_many :companies, through: :officers
end

class Officer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Comment: So this would imply that I need to add a `role_id` column to the officers?

Comment: Make sure that the migration, which is related to your Officer model, contains

t.references :company
t.references :role

That will add the needed foreign keys